# Using XMPP over GTalk to simulate push notifications

Tags: android, google-app-engine, xmpp, real-time, google-talk

I'm currently writing an Android application that should be able to receive push notifications from another application hosted in Google's App Engine.
Since I can't use sockets in GAE, I though maybe using XMPP over GTalk server would solve my problem. But that way the Android Application would be connected to the users Gtalk account and thus showing the user as being online, when in reality the user is not.

Any way of achieving this kind of communication without showing the user as being online, and without asking the user to create a separate account?

Or any **free** push notification alternatives?

EDIT:
I'm targeting 1.5+ Android devices so C2DM isn't an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the PubNub service (http://www.pubnub.com/).
It enables push notifications through API's on several platforms (PHP, Ruby, JavaScript, Java, ...).
It's a paid service, but provides a free daily quota.

Although it's not the ideal solution to my problem, it'll have to suffice until some Channel API documentation comes out.

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 2):

May be you can use the channel API: [Building real-time web apps with App Engine and the Feed API](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/building-real-time-apps-app-engine-feed-api.html)

Comment: It seems like a good solution, but isn't it still inactive on the production server?

Comment: I think its activated because the demo is online: http://io-trivia-quiz.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks, although there's no documentation I tried analyzing the source code here http://code.google.com/p/trivia-quiz/source/browse/trunk/src/iodemo.py?spec=svn11&r=11 but still wouldn't know how to create a channel on the Android app... I'm new to all this app engine & android stuff so please excuse some "noobism".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the exact requirement of your app, but.. perhaps C2DM can be an alternative?
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm

Comment: One of my objectives is to make the app functional to older versions of android, and afaik C2DM it's currently only available to Android 2.2...

I've already considered other options like the MQTT protocol (http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/) or building my own application server, but I can't afford a server that would have to be always-on to serve my application...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you shying away from HTTP/JSON?  Might be useful to know why you discounted the obvious solution...

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not really familiar with JSON. But after a little research it looks like JSON it's a lightweight XML alternative... Also, making HTTP requests and getting the responses won't to because sometimes the server response won't be ready right away, timing out the connection. What I am missing here? :s

Comment: Telmo, you are correct. PubNub is a "two-way internet JSON radio" as the song goes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZgcEj_qKLU